# Why wont this if statement work in javascript

Tags: javascript, express

I got bored and decided to make a simple API in javascript. big mistake.

For some reason this very simple if/else statement will only run the code in `if`, instead of `else`. I have asked my friend who is more experienced in javascript than I am, but he can't see an issue either.

here is the code:

```
app.get("/number", (req, res) => {
    const min = req.query.min || 0
    const max = req.query.max || 100

    if (min > max) {
        res.status(400).json({
            error: "min must be less than max. ur actually dumb"
        })
    } else {
        const number = Math.floor(Math.random()*Math.max(min, max)+Math.min(min, max))

        res.json({
            number: number,
            "your ip LEAKED 2021 not clickbait!!!11!1": req.ip
        })
    }
})
```

here is the output: [image: Image of output]

so here I am, asking stack overflow to help me with an if statement. thank you

Comment: *"For some reason this very simple if/else statement will only run the code in else."* And yet your screenshot shows the opposite. Please clarify the problem.

Comment: `min` and `max` are probably strings, which work differently than numbers. With strings, `'6' > '20'`. Try `parseInt(min) > parseInt(max)` and see if that helps?

Comment: what values are `req.query.min` and `req.query.max ` as long as you din't show what they are, any answer here will be speculative, and your question will stay a stupid enigm, like "what do I have in my hand"

Comment: the values are in the image. anyways, my issue is solved; just waiting 30 seconds to mark it as resolved. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`min` and `max` are strings since they're passed in as query arguments

You also don't need `Math.min` or `Math.max` since you already know which is bigger/smaller

Also use the ternary operators instead of `||` since if max is `0`, then max will be set to 100

```js
app.get("/number", (req, res) => {
    const min = isNaN(parseInt(req.query.min)) ? 0 : parseInt(req.query.min);
    const max = isNaN(parseInt(req.query.max)) ? 100 : parseInt(req.query.max);

    if (min > max) {
        res.status(400).json({
            error: "min must be less than max. ur actually dumb"
        });
    } else {
        const number = Math.floor(Math.random()*max+min);

        res.json({
            number: number,
            "your ip LEAKED 2021 not clickbait!!!11!1": req.ip
        });
    }
})
```

Comment: `const min = +req.query.min || 0; const max = +req.query.max || 100;` is probably good enough.

Comment: @FelixKling But that still has the issue of `max` becoming `100` if it is `"0"`

Answer (score -1):

you must parse req.query.min and req.query.max to integer
otherwise, comparison won't work in the correct way

```
app.get("/number", (req, res) => {
  const min = isNaN(parseInt(req.query.min)) ? 0 : 
    parseInt(req.query.min);
  const max = isNaN(parseInt(req.query.max)) ? 100 : 
   parseInt(req.query.max);

  if (min > max) {
    res.status(400).json({
        error: "min must be less than max. ur actually dumb"
    });
  } else {
    const number = Math.floor(Math.random()*max+min);

    res.json({
        number: number,
        "your ip LEAKED 2021 not clickbait!!!11!1": req.ip
    });
  }
  })
```

Comment: This is literally the same as my answer except for spacing

Comment: @Samathingamajig your code has a mistake on the third line at the ternary operator you checked with isNan again so your code will not work as expected